# How to apply a tintColor to a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` that is a small symbol that is all black. The `UIImage` is getting set in a custom `UIButton` subclass I have. Is it possible to have the image to apply the `tintColor` to it, so instead of the black image it changes colors to whatever the `tintColor` is?

I'm just trying to avoid creating new assets.

```
// here I want defaultImageName (that is black) to use the tintColor (that is white)
[self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:defaultImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274789/how-can-i-change-image-tintcolor-in-ios-and-watchkit) change image tintColor in iOS and WatchKit

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you are just supporting iOS 7 you can use `tintColor` and `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`

This article covers that:

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming

If you need to support an earlier version you may want to consider this thread

[How would I tint an image programmatically on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117211/how-would-i-tint-an-image-programatically-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Please note that using templates might impact performance since it is always composited on the fly

Comment: You need to setup your UIImage so it draws the image as a template image, ignoring its color information: `UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];`. And then the tint color will be applied, set that on your UIImageView: `_imageView.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: Unfortunately the first Llink is dead

Comment: [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150510110717/https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming) link

Comment: LINK is dead. Please update this answer with the correct details

Comment: The link no longer works

Answer (score 26):

Swift 4, copy-paste solution

```
@IBOutlet weak var iconImageView: UIImageView!
iconImageView.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "myImageName").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
iconImageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: WARNING: I would like to add that if you perform any task that returns a new image, you WILL need to set `withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` again. Example: if you use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` to resize image. This also applies if you set an asset image to Template rendering mode.

Answer (score 11):

On iOS 13+ you can use the following:

```
UIImage(named: "img_name")?.withTintColor(.red)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3327300-withtintcolor

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
func tinted(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
    color.set()
    self.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

For example:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle")?.tinted(with: .systemGray), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I use tint colors and opacities in IOS 9 with Swift -

```
//apply a color to an image
//ref - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427935/how-can-i-change-image-tintcolor
//ref - https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming
func getTintedImage() -> UIImageView {

    var image :UIImage
    var imageView :UIImageView

    image = UIImage(named: "someAsset")!
    let size  : CGSize = image.size
    let frame : CGRect = CGRectMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-86)/2, 600, size.width, size.height)

    let redCover : UIView = UIView(frame: frame)

    redCover.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    redCover.layer.opacity = 0.75

    imageView = UIImageView();
    imageView.image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.Automatic)

    imageView.addSubview(redCover)

    return imageView
}
```

Comment: I dislike this solution because it doesn't tint the image. Instead it reduces the contrast by using a second layer and making one of the (depends on z order) semi transparent. You also can never achieve a satisfying saturation of the tint color.

Comment: quite interesting. Please send over or post here some tips or url links to help me then generate and post here an alternative solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use image filtering

```
btn.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
btn.setImage(image.disabled, for: UIControl.State.disabled)
```

Use CoreImage to do image filter

```
extension UIImage
{
    /// Create a grayscale image with alpha channel. Is 5 times faster than grayscaleImage().
    /// - Returns: The grayscale image of self if available.
    var disabled: UIImage?
    {
        // Create image rectangle with current image width/height * scale
        let pixelSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width * self.scale, height: self.size.height * self.scale)
        let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: pixelSize)
        // Grayscale color space
         let colorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

            // Create bitmap content with current image size and grayscale colorspace
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
        if let context: CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(pixelSize.width), height: Int(pixelSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
            {
                // Draw image into current context, with specified rectangle
                // using previously defined context (with grayscale colorspace)
                guard let cg = self.cgImage else{
                    return nil
                }
                context.draw(cg, in: imageRect)
                // Create bitmap image info from pixel data in current context
                if let imageRef: CGImage = context.makeImage(){
                    let bitmapInfoAlphaOnly = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue)

                    guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(pixelSize.width), height: Int(pixelSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfoAlphaOnly.rawValue) else{
                        return nil
                    }
                    context.draw(cg, in: imageRect)
                    if let mask: CGImage = context.makeImage() {
                        // Create a new UIImage object
                        if let newCGImage = imageRef.masking(mask){
                            // Return the new grayscale image
                            return UIImage(cgImage: newCGImage, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


        // A required variable was unexpected nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

Of course, in Swift 5

Answer (score 1):

**Swift5 Extension**

```
extension UIImage {
    var template: UIImage? {
         return self.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

- UIImageView

  ```
  let imgView = UIImageView()
  imgView.tintColor = UIColor.red
  imgView.image = UIImage(named: "IMAGE_NAME_HERE")?.template
  ```
- UIButton

  ```
  let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
  button.tintColor = UIColor.red
  button.setImage(UIImage(named: "IMAGE_NAME_HERE")?.template, for: .normal)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple extension to UIImageView

```
@IBInspectable var tintedColor: UIColor{
    get{
        return tintColor
    }
    set{
        image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        tintColor = newValue
    }
}
```