# Can an UIImage have a tintColor that reflects the background?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, gradient

I have an `imageView` in a cell and I can customize the `imageTint` color. I would like for the imageTint to reflect this gradient behind it, so that that when the user scrolls, the `imageTint` of the image changes with the background.

Here is what the imageView looks like when I make the `tintColor` dark.

[image]

If I make the `imageTint` clear, I can't see it because of the white background of the imageView.
[image]

However, if I make the background of the imageView clear AND the imageTint clear, then nothing shows up at all.

Ideally, I want the end product to look like this:
[image]

Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way? Maybe I should calculate the gradient colors while the user is scrolling and change them for each individual cell?

Comment: Maybe you can invert the transparency of your images?

Answer (score 0):

mostly I use always this

```
ImageView.image = ImageView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
ImageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

// or any color you want

also can you show your code if it need some fixing 
and what is the image type you are using ?

Comment: The image is a PNG. I want the black lines to be transparent, but if the imageView.backgroundColor is white, then the imageView background is blocking the black lines, so they can't reflect the gradient colors.

Comment: you want to remove the blue background and the black line also ? to make the image clear from all these ?

Comment: check this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37680479/13175039